# Why is independence of observations an assumption in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

I am currently learning about the assumptions of logistic regression and am having a hard time wrapping my head around *why* independence of observations is necessary for this test. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Independence is not necessary, but it leads to a tractable model.  I find it illuminating to consider the inverse of this question: if you think the observations are not independent, then exactly what form of independence do you have in mind?

Comment: I marked it as a duplicate of two other threads that seem to answer your question.